# I don´t get this result, of Trig Substitution in functions.

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I got this integral:

$\int\frac{2}{x\sqrt{x^2-5}}dx$

And, at the end I got:

$\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}arcsec\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}+c$

Why the text's answer is?

$\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}arcsec\frac{\sqrt{5}x}{5}+c$

I'm pretty sure that this should be a really easy answer, but...I need to know.

Comment: It falls under the term "rationalizing the denominator."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same, because
$$
\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}\sqrt{5}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}=\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5} \cdot \sqrt{5}}$$